# Photoshop: How to duplicate a layer below the original layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I use `Alt + Shift` to duplicate a layer, however, the layer always gets created **above** the layer I'm duplicating.

How can I duplicate it and have the layer automatically go below the layer I'm duplicating?

Comment: Howabout recording a action with duplicate and move layer down?

Comment: You could use the keyboard shortcut cmd + [ to move a layer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution suggestion:

1. Download the action from the link below
2. https://cudadrive.com/lrJ9Bmtz2HNlFqMR
3. Load it to Photoshop
4. Highlight the layer (other than Background) you want to duplicate below itself
5. Run the action

The new copy of the layer will be below the current one

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate a layer CTRL/CMD + J and move the top of the 2 layers.